# Effect of arc welding on nearby electronic devices

Tags: electromagnetism

Will an electronic device,say a smartphone or wifi router, get damaged if there is an arc welding going on in the vicinity? I am not talking about damage from direct contact with the fire/spark, but the electromagnetic pulse.

Comment: What warnings are in the instruction / owner's manual for the smartphone / router? This seems to be a recurring question type at the moment. And, should it be in Electrical Engineering anyway?

Comment: @SolarMike  given the fact that all these related questions come from 1-point members, I strongly suspect a single person who doesn't understand how to re-use an account.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft you could be right there!

Comment: @CarlWitthoft 1 point members with 3-letter names.  Kinda odd.

Answer (score 1):

The arc does produce a certain amount of RF interference which can certainly disrupt electronic devices in some circumstances but won't usually cause any permanent damage. Some welding machines have additional earthing points on the chassis which can be used to mitigate this if it is a problem.

TIG welders often use a high frequency pulse to make it easier to start the arc this can be a problem for sensitive equipment nearby and some machines have the facility to disable the HF start.

Unless you are dealing with equipment which is especially sensitive you are only likely to cause actual damage if the device is electrically connected to the structure that is being welded (eg the ecu of a vehicle).

Welders, especially transformer based ones can also induce noise and voltage spikes in the circuit they are connected to.